# Qt Installer window title

Tags: windows, qt, installation, qt-installer

Is there any way to change the window title of installer that created by *Qt installer framework*?
The window title set by `<Title>` tag from the *config.xml* that concatenated with **"Setup"**.
there is a *title* property for pages but it change the title of page contained inside the tab controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late, but I recently had to deal with the same.

You have to change the sources

src\libs\installer\packagemanagergui.cpp - line 300 (v3.0.2)

```
PackageManagerGui::PackageManagerGui(PackageManagerCore *core, QWidget *parent)
    : QWizard(parent)
    , d(new Private)
    , m_core(core)
{
    if (m_core->isInstaller())
        setWindowTitle(tr("%1 Setup").arg(m_core->value(scTitle)));
    else
        setWindowTitle(tr("Maintain %1").arg(m_core->value(scTitle)));
    setWindowFlags(windowFlags() &~ Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recompiled the code without any changes to source code and only changed the translation files of Qt Installer Framework.